# How to make code do something if file isn't found in Python?

Tags: python, error-handling, file-handling

I would like to have a check for save games for a command-line game I'm working on.

The save games are singular `".txt"` files, and the way this short piece of code works is it tries to open the `"name.txt"` file in the `"%appdata%\Roaming\AdventureChapt1\"` folder, then looks for an error message when Python can't find the file.

How would I do this?

```
print('Loading Save Data')

savecheck = open('%appdata%/Roaming/AdventureChapt1/name.txt', 'rt')

if savecheck.read() == '':
    newgame() # calls the "newgame" function to bring up the New Game wizard
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `try` and `except`

```
try:
    with open('%appdata%/Roaming/AdventureChapt1/name.txt', 'rt') as savecheck:
        # code that reads saved game
except FileNotFoundError:
    newgame()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variety of things to see if the file exists or not.
My flavour is

```py
from os import path
filepath = "path_to_file"
if not path.exists(filepath):
    # do stuff when file doesn't exist
```

ref: https://www.guru99.com/python-check-if-file-exists.html